# how to trigger enter event in text box without pressing enter in javascript

Tags: javascript

i'm working on computing the product of two textboxes. However, the user needs to press "enter" before the txtTotal will show the total value. Pls I really need help. I'm not really familiar with jquery, and I'm still studying jscript. Thank you so much !

Here is my updated code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>

$('#txtQuantity').bind('input',function(){ 
 var quantity = parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
 var amount = parseFloat($('#txtAmount').val());
 var evt = (amount * quantity);
 $('#txttotal').val(evt);
});

</script>
</head>

<body>

<input type="text" class="quan1" name="txtQuantity" id="txtQuantity"/> 
<input type="text"  id="txtAmount" class="quan1" name="txtAmount"   value="4" disabled="" /> 
<input type="text" class="quan1" id="txttotal" name="txttotal"  disabled="" /> <br>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var e = $.Event( "keypress", { which: 13 } );
$('#yourInput').trigger(e);
```

hope this helps

**Extra** : Read  [Events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) and
[Triggers](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

if you are using jquery you can do like this.

**Solution 1**

```
$('#txtQuantity').on('keypress', function (event) {
       if(event.which === 13){

     var quantity = parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
     var amount = parseFloat($('#txtAmount').val());
     var evt = (amount * quantity);
     $('#txttotal').val(evt);
     }
 });
```

[**Solution 1 Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gayanstar/rc7scdvs/)

**Solution 2**

```
$('#txtQuantity').bind('input',function(){ 
     var quantity = parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
     var amount = parseFloat($('#txtAmount').val());
     var evt = (amount * quantity);
     $('#txttotal').val(evt);
});
```

[**Solution 2 Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gayanstar/0n8hadza/)

**Note:**
In HTML5 there is a new event, "input", which behaves exactly like you seem to think "change" should have behaved - in that it fires as soon as a key is pressed to enter information into a form. older browsers you can use the "Keyup" event.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for responding immediately ! I really appreciate it ! I tried your code  like this ==>  <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>


$('#txtQuantity').on('keypress', function (event) {
       if(event.which === 13){

     var quantity = parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
     var amount = parseFloat($('#txtAmount').val());
     var evt = (amount * quantity);
     $('#txttotal').val(evt);
     }
 });


</script>  .. however it did not work and i'm not so sure if the problem is how i called the function or i'm not really sure. :( Please help me analyze it.

Comment: i also tried this ==> <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
var e = $.Event( "onchange", { which: 13 } );
        $('#txtQuantity').trigger(e);

function jsComputeTotal(evt){

        var quantity = parseFloat(document.js.txtQuantity.value) || 0;
        var amount = parseFloat(document.js.txtAmount.value);
        var evt = parseFloat(document.js.txttotal.value);

        evt = (amount * quantity);
        document.getElementById("txttotal").value = evt ;
        return false;
}
</script>

and adding onchange="return jsComputeTotal(event)" to txtQuantity but it did not work :(

Comment: i saw your Demo, and it is also the same as my code above sir... I would really like to compute without pressing enter?

Comment: what is the event you want to trigger.

Comment: if you want to trigger the event without pressing enter use change event.

Comment: yes sir change event, but i also tried it and it did not work. $('#txtQuantity').on('change', function (event) {
       if(event.which === 13){

     var quantity = parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
     var amount = parseFloat($('#txtAmount').val());
     var evt = (amount * quantity);
     $('#txttotal').val(evt);
     }
 });

Comment: hi sir, hi! yes this is exactly what i'm looking for !! Thank you so much for this... I just have a slight problem in implementing it on my page... what have i done wrong here??

Comment: <html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#txtQuantity').bind('input',function(){ 
         var quantity = parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
         var amount = parseFloat($('#txtAmount').val());
         var evt = (amount * quantity);
         $('#txttotal').val(evt);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" class="quan1" name="txtQuantity" id="txtQuantity"/> 
<input type="text"  id="txtAmount" class="quan1" name="txtAmount"   value="4" disabled="" /> 
<input type="text" class="quan1" id="txttotal" name="txttotal"  disabled="" /> <br>
</body>
</html>

Comment: its very difficult to read the code in comment section please add it to main area il try to help you. i mean update the question.

Comment: seems like there is no issue in code. is there any error in console.

Comment: aww.. okay. sorry sir it's my first time posting here. I'll update it then .

Comment: yes sir i think that there is no issue in the code anymore but i'm not really sure why it's not working...

Comment: Oh my, I already checked everything.. there is no error in console and jquery is loaded correclty.. what did i do wrong here ?

Comment: not working means whats happening. is the function fireing. check with alert.

Comment: it's not really working... however my first code works whenever i try to change the function....

Answer (score 0):

If you need to compute the value immediatly whithout the user pressing enter, bind a keyup event to the text box

```
var compute = function(){
     var quantity = parseFloat($("#txtQuantity" ).val()) || 0;
     var amount = parseFloat($('#txtAmount').val());
     var total = (amount * quantity);
     $('#txttotal').val(total);
}

 $( "#txtQuantity" ).keyup(compute);
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for responding so fast.. I tried your code sir .. i just put this in the script var compute = function (){
        var quantity = parseFloat(document.js.txtQuantity.value) || 0;
        var amount = parseFloat(document.js.txtAmount.value);
        var compute = parseFloat(document.js.txttotal.value);

        compute = (amount * quantity);
      

}

$("#txtQuantity").change(compute);
$("#txtAmount").change(compute);.. but then it is not working. Please help me analyze your code maybe i did not understand your instruction.. Thank you. Please bare with me.

Comment: The solution wasnt working because the change event was being trigged after the element loosed its focus. The new solution shoud work as expected.